# Is it possible to create multiples forms with one view

Tags: django, forms

I would like to create a comment form for each attribute of my model. Usually, I would have a view and one form for each model attribute. The thing is that for 30 attributes I don't want to create 30 forms and 30 views. Is there a way to create one view and one form for all attributes then have a comment form for each attribute?

My model is:

```
class Project(models.Model):

   attribut1 = models.CharField(choices=PROJECT_STATUS,default=1)
   attribut2 = models.CharField(choices=PROJECT_STATUS,default=1)
   attribut3 = models.CharField(choices=PROJECT_STATUS,default=1)
   attribut4 = models.CharField(choices=PROJECT_STATUS,default=1)
   attribut5 = models.CharField(choices=PROJECT_STATUS,default=1)
   attribut6 = models.CharField(choices=PROJECT_STATUS,default=1)
   attribut7 = models.CharField(choices=PROJECT_STATUS,default=1)
```

My form is:

```
class ScopeForm(forms.ModelForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ScopeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for field in self.fields:
        self.fields[field].required = False

class Meta:
    model = Project
    fields = ['project_scope',]
```

Comment: What does this mean? What is a "comment form" for an integer attribute? How is the comment relate to the integer? And *why* do you need a separate form for each one, anyway?

Comment: I've corrected IntegerField by CharField.It was the wrong example. What I called a comment form is a form with a text area or the comment box. The thing is in my forms I've got 30 attributes, like project_name, project_scope... I don't want them to be null. If I put all of them in one form like I used to do, I will have to fill the text area immediately. But sometimes, I don't have that information yet, so I was thinking to separate the attributes in differents forms. And the second argument is that it would be quicker to find a field in a form with one text area than having 30 text area.